# How to bring multiplication and division symbol in html?

Tags: html, xhtml

I need to bring multiplication and division symbol in html codes.How to do that

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use the appropriate [entities](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/latin1.html).

`&times;` for `×`

`&divide;` for `÷`

Comment: ... or just copy-paste the actual symbols to your HTML/XHTML source. :)

Comment: @VictorNicollet All browsers don't like that! :)

Answer (score 10):

Do you mean * and /  or ÷ and × ?
The codes for the latter are:

```
&divide; or &#247;
&times; or &#215;
```

http://www.visibone.com/products/ebk2-3_850.jpg

Answer (score 1):

The extended ASCII code for the divide symbol is `247`; try putting it into your page like this: `&#247;`. As for the multiply symbol, just use the `x` character.

James